# Client compliance, client's compliance or a client's compliance?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, adjectives, articles

I'm working on a job application covering note and I'm really struggling with one particular phrase. Here's the full sentence:

"I possess strong analytical and investigative skills as demonstrated by successfully investigating improper market trading, or analysing **client’s compliance** with FCA regulations."

Should it be

**client's compliance**,

**client compliance** or

**a client's compliance**?

The last one sounds a bit weird to me as it seems to take away the weight from the term 'client' and makes it sound random. On the other hand, 'client' is a singular countable noun, so under all rules I can recall, it needs to have an article. As it is the first time I'm mentioning any client in the note (and I don't expect the recruiter to know anything about it) I'm pretty sure using 'the' as an article would not be correct.

Not sure if it matters but the client in question is a corporate client, i.e. a business not an individual.

Please let me now if you have any ideas on how to approach this. I tried googling but it gets me absolutely nowhere.

Could also someone explain what would each of these phrases mean in practice to a native English speaker? Would any of them sound wrong altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would make it clear that you have done this only once by saying "a client's compliance" -- otherwise your reader may assume you have done it often and that *client's* for *clients'* is a solecism. I'd also link these two succesful activities with *and* rather than *or*.

Answer (score 2):

These are mainly stylistic choices but I believe this reads smoother without changing your intended message.

> "I possess strong analytical and investigative skills as demonstrated by **my success** investigating improper market trading **and** analysing **client** compliance with FCA regulations."